# How to sort a table with specific/some rows always on top in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to code this query in Codeigniter using active record?

```
"SELECT * FROM `my_table` ORDER BY clm_name != 2 ASC"
```

[image]

Comment: you can't use operator  in  ORDER BY clm_name != 2  ( you should use ORDER BY clm_name  ASC ) you can use opearator in where .. please explain better you goal

Comment: Yes, I know CodeIgniter order_by() method don't accept operators.
I want to sort a table by its id in ascending order but want some/single row(s) to be selected at the first position of selection!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put `pic_id = 2` on **top always** and prefer a natural order (`ascending/descending`) for the rest of the `pic_id`s then follow the query given below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pictures
ORDER BY (pic_id <> 2) , pic_id ASC;
```

---

If you want to put `pic_id (2)` to the **bottom always** then:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pictures
ORDER BY (pic_id = 2) , pic_id ASC;
```

**Note:**

MySQL boolean expression resolves into `0/1`. 
So for `pic_id 2` `(pic_id <> 2) returns 0` then the order by looks like `ORDER BY 0, <pic_id>` and the order by looks like `ORDER BY 1, <pic_id>` for the rest of the pic ids other than `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an alias  eg using a case statement for assigne the value you need to the alias column and the order by the alias name

```
$this->db->select(' col1, col2 , 
        case clm_name when !=2 then 100 else clm_name end as my_clm_name');
$this->db->from('my_table');
$this->db->order_by('my_clm_name   asc');
```